# How to use variables with pug mixin in angular?

Tags: angular, pug

I'm trying to build a mixin with with pug that takes an angular variable as an input and shows the input data.  I can get it work with a string but not when I try and include an async data value.  How could I do this?

```
//component.view.pug
h3 {{ (item | async)?.firstname }} {{ (item | async)?.lastname }}
+myMixin(item)


mixin pre(data)
    pre.bg-dark {{ data| async | json}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pug is server-side and angular is client-side.  Your question can't be answered with anything but "it can't be done" because these two platforms don't interoperate like this.

To solve your problem you can render the Angular code in the pug mixin:

```
mixin pre(data)
  pre.bg-dark(ngClass="!{data}| async | json"}
```

I'm not 100% sure which variable is which in your pasted code, but in the example above `data` comes from pug, and both `async` and `json` are Angular variables.